# VSCode showing {%commnet%} {%endcommnet%} when I try to comment code section in HTML?

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to comment a code section in HTML file using my VS code shortcut keys for comments, instead of placing `/**/` or `//` I am getting `{%commnet%}{%endcomment%}` from nowhere.

```
{%commnet%}
    <ion-tab-button tab="speakers">
          <ion-icon name="contacts"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>Speakers</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
{%endcommnet%}
```

does any of my extension is causing it? how can I fix this? please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/61348 ?

Comment: thank you find the issue,

For me, it was the (Djaneiro) extension, it made the html files default to django template, so it caused the comments to be wrong in HTML (when pressing ctrl + / ) (commenting them with {% comment %})